# Given a NxN grid and an integer calculate the row and column

Tags: algorithms, programming, index-notation

I know this is most likely elementary school math, but I am having hard time finding a good algorithm. Given a NxN grid and a number which represents the nth tile counting left to right like a typewriter, where at the end of the row you return to column 1... e.g. given a grid of 20x20 and the number is 21, 21 would be located in column 1 row 2. Another example 36 in a 20x20 grid would be column 16 row 2. And so on.

What is the formula I can use to find the row and column.

I tried using modulo to find the column and division for the row, but it just does not work yet.

Comment: Is this called [division with remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a similar problem, where you have indices starting from $0$. In other words, you have a grid with $m$ rows and $n$ columns and you need to find the index of some number.

For simplicity let's look at $n=10$ first, letting $m=30$. Then, entry $0$ maps to $(0,0)$, and we follow with similar relationships below:

- $0 \mapsto 0,0$
- $1 \mapsto 0,1$
- \ldots
- $9 \mapsto 0,9$
- $10 \mapsto 1,0$
- \ldots
- $19 \mapsto 1,9$

This may be enough to get the pattern. The entry number $N$ maps the second coordinate as $N \pmod{10}$ and the first coordinate is $\lfloor N \div 10 \rfloor$ which we will for convenience denote $N//10$.

In full generality, we map $N \mapsto N//n,N \pmod n$.

---

The problem you posed is slightly more tricky, since indexing is $1$-based, so given $N$ you translate it to the $N$ from the above problem by subtracting one, then map, and add 1 to compensate, so you get
$$
N \mapsto 1 + [(N-1)//n], 1+[(N-1) \pmod n]
$$

---

Useful to note that on most computing systems, the first operation is denoted `div` and the second `mod`. In addition, some have the faster `divmod` which does both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What does the `//` mean in this case?

Comment: I see it's division, but is it a `ceil` or `floor` division? Or just rounding?

Comment: @Johnston I defined it in the post above - it is a floor

Comment: I see it now I missed that!